# <div> and <span> not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript

Currently I am trying to use `<div>` and `<span>` tags as labels for my JavaScript. This works when using IE and Google Chrome, but does not work in FireFox. The JavaScript Error Console says "imgNo is not defined".

This is the function where I set the div tag:

```
function next_picture() {
        if (document.images) {
            if (pictureNum < 21) {
                pictureNum++;
                document.TravelAlberta.src = picture[pictureNum].src;
                imgNo.innerHTML = "Image " + (pictureNum + 1) + " of 22";
            }
            else
                alert("This is last picture");
        }
        else
            alert("Your browser does not support images");
    }
```

This is the code in the Body

```
<div id="imgNo" class="style1">
    Image 1 of 22</div>
<p class="style1">
    <img alt="" class="style3" src="images/back_button.gif" id="Back" name="Back" onclick="back_picture()" />

    <img alt="" class="style4" src="images/next_button.gif" id="Next" name="Next" onclick="next_picture()" /></p>
```

Comment: I expect what the tutor meant to write was `document.images.TravelAlberta.src` where *TravelAlberta* is the **name** of the related image element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad practice is causing your problem. Some browser will use element ids for variable names if the variable is not defined. You should use getElementById.

```
document.getElementById("imgNo").innerHTML = "Image " + (pictureNum + 1) + " of 22";
```

Comment: @RobG it has nothing to do with `document.images`. The poster was referencing a `div` via its `id`.

Comment: @epascarello - worth noting that the [document.images](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/Overview.html#dom-document-images) collection has been around for a very long time (it's part of DOM 0 and now HTML5). As with similar collections like document.forms, if the members have a `name` attribute, they are made available as named properties of the document. Therefore if you have markup like `<img name="img0"...>` you can reference the image as `document.images['img0']` or, `'document['img0']`. If the name is a valid identifier, dot notation can be used: `document.img0`.

Comment: @RobG Why are you all up on document.images still, it has nothing to do with the problem. In this format or in the previous one. lol